# Get all data in specified time and list all this transaction too in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, subquery, cross-apply, partition-by

I have this demo database

```
create database testGroupfirst22;
go

use testGroupfirst22;
go

create table testTbl 
(
    id int primary key identity,
    custnum nvarchar(50),
    transDate datetime,
    degree int 
)

insert into testTbl 
values ('ahmed', '1-1-2000', 50), ('ahmed', '1-1-2000', 500),
       ('ahmed', '2-1-2000', 660), ('ahmed', '2-1-2000', 666),
       ('ahmed', '3-1-2000', 50),
       ('ali', '1-1-2000', 5054), ('ali', '1-1-2000', 1500),
       ('ali', '1-1-2000', 66220), ('ali', '1-1-2000', 6656),
       ('ali', '1-1-2000', 540),
       ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 50), ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 50),
       ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 500), ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 660),
       ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 666), ('hasan', '1-1-2000', 50)
```

This is the output

[image]

I wrote this code to get all transaction in specified time that more than 1950
and it worked like this

```
select 
    custnum, sum(degree) as [all transaction] 
from 
    testTbl
where 
    transdate between '1-1-2000' and '3-1-2000' 
group by 
    custnum
having 
    sum(degree) > 2000
```

Output:

[image]

But I need to list all this transaction and history of it with the same code 
like this

[image]

I believe that this could be happen using subquery but I think that there are  a performance issues using this and I found many questions that recommend using cross apply and other window - ranking but I'm not familiar with these ways and I got stuck with this query and I couldn't reach to the wright solution yet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe for a second that you will have performance issues by shoving this into a subquery.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM testTbl
WHERE custnum IN
    (
        SELECT custnum
        FROM testTbl
        WHERE transdate BETWEEN '1-1-2000'  AND '3-1-2000'
        GROUP BY custnum
        HAVING sum(degree) > 2000
    )
```

Index on custnum and you should be fine here.

Comment: thanks for your comment, this code would be run in an environment that contains more than 1 million customers with their transaction, and I'm a newbie in SQL server and always heard that subqueries should be eliminated and use window and ranking when this is an available , so, please correct me or explain why this is not a true @JNevill

Comment: You could use window functions here, but it would have to be in a subquery where your outer query filters the results. That would probably be more expensive though. Don't hold to any "Must do" advice. Write sql that works, look at the EXPLAIN plan, rewrite it to do the same thing, check that EXPLAIN. Tune your environment to work well with the SQL you land on (Indexing, and the like).